# Implementing a Array programming language in C. What is the best and most efficient struct for the arrays?

Tags: language-design, implementation, arrays, pointers, apl

```
// #include <stdio.h>
// #include <unistd.h>

// typedef int I;
// typedef char C;



// I main(){C b[99];C*s=b;while(read(0,s,98))printf("%s",s);}
```

That is my REPL for now, I need to create a struct to hold my arrays and allocate memory for them. As well as make a parser.

```
Let say I will use only Int and String type for now.
Let say array are formed like that [1,2,3] or even 1,2,3 and string are just inside "", char inside '' and a string is an array of Char.
Then I need to define some operation like + * and -
About defining variables (let say I use : so x:3 is creating the x variable and x is a int with value 3)
```

Arrays are the core variables in array language it could be implemented for example with:

```
typedef struct a {
    int32_t rank;         // number of dimensions
    int32_t *shape;       // array of dimension sizes
    void *data;           // pointer to array data
    int32_t element_size; // size of each element in bytes
} *A;
```

What struct should I define for arrays for it to be practical en efficient(I want to support multidimensional array, reduce, map and so on)?

There is some information about it here https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Array_model but it is all talk and no `code`.

I am not sure what I need for what functionality of my array language, I could use some explanation and example. If I enter `a:[1,2,3]` or `b:[1,[2,3]]` in the REPL I would like to do `2*a` and get `[2,4,6]` or `2*b` and get `[2,[4,6]]`.

Thanks you

ps:I edited the question and removed the part about REPL variables because @kaya3 point me to a good answer.

Comment: This is really two separate questions, though "What is the best and most efficient struct for the arrays?" doesn't make sense to me, because an array *is* a data structure. The main question about REPLs seems to be answered [here](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/q/1176/89) ─ if that's not what you're looking for, please edit to clarify.

Comment: An "Array Programming Language" has a specific meaning and it not just a language that has arrays but is a language whose operators take arrays as arguments. Is this indeed what this is about? If, by any chance, this is a homework assignment it should be disclosed.

Comment: You will need to enumerate what operations and capabilities you want to support and then design your internal data structures to support them.  For example, [slices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_slicing), which are in several modern languages.

Comment: *"There is some information about it here ... but it is all talk and no code."* ─ any answer you get here is likely to also be "all talk and no code". If your question expects an answer that is mostly code, [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) is a better bet, but make sure to read their [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not share the data part, the most efficient layout is moving the data to the end as zero-sized array and *implement* the arrays with generated struct definition appending the correct array size after the common header struct.